# Do I need to use Locks for my Inserts and Deletes for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've created a number of C# classes that create dynamic SQL to perform inserts and deletes. If the requirement is to do an update then a delete is done first, then an insert.

Reading these two articles on MSDN makes me think that I don't need to use Locks. Is this a safe assumption?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

I realise that this is potentially an open question I'm just after advice along the lines of :Yes, you'll be fine or No, add locks regardless of what Microsoft says.

Comment: Why not just use [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Comment: I'm taking data from a non-SQL source, constructing SQL and using that to write to SQL data tables. It's part of a planned migration. I didn't know about merge until you mentioned it though so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

These two articles on MSDN suggest that there is no need to use Locks when inserting and deleting. Furthermore they suggest that the ability to suggest table hints for these two operations will be removed.

```
The ability to specify the HOLDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE, READCOMMITTED, REPEATABLEREAD, 
or UPDLOCK hints on tables that are targets of INSERT statements will be removed 
in a future version of SQL Server. These hints do not affect the performance of 
INSERT statements. Avoid using them in new development work, and plan to modify   
applications that currently use them.
```